# Images are cropped in MasterSlider jquery plugin

Tags: php, jquery

I am using MasterSlider plugin in my PHP/MySQL application. I am using the following configuration :

```
var categorySlider = new MasterSlider();

categorySlider.setup('prod-gal' , {
        width:550,  
        height:484, 
        speed: 25,  
        preload:'all',  
        loop:true,  
        view:'fade'});
```

I tried various configuration settings described here : http://masterslider.com/doc/ with no success.

However, the images are cropped on the sides. Any idea how to fit the images using MasterSlider plugin ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
Exemple

if($('#cat-slider').length > 0) {
  var categorySlider = new MasterSlider();
  categorySlider.control('thumblist' , {autohide:false, dir:'h', type:'thumbs', width:50, height:50, align:'bottom', space:10, margin:15, hideUnder:200});
  categorySlider.setup('cat-slider' , {
    width:1050,
    height:550,
    space:0,
    speed: 25,
    layout: 'boxed',
    preload:'all',
    view:'fade',
    instantStartLayers: true
  });
 }
```